# Copy DynamoDB table while modifying key attribute

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, data-migration, amazon-data-pipeline

I have a DynamoDB table with hundreds of thousands of data, which I need it duplicated, with one catch that the key needs to be modified. The current key is a combination of 2 fields, e.g. `attr1:attr2`. I need the new table to have the key consisted only from `attr1`.

I know copying the table with Data pipelines is pretty straight forward, but how do I do the new key creation according to the use case I have?

Note: the data size is between 500K and 1M items.

Answer (score 1):

Use Elastic Map Reduce in order to manipulate the data. This [article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-howto-using-amazon-elastic-mapreduce-with-dynamodb/) explains how to handle DynamoDB data with EMR. Create a [UDF](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-scala.html) which will parse and manipulate the key and use that in a comprehensive

```
    SELECT UDF(id), all, other, columns FROM your_table
```

Which will be saved in another DynamoDB table.